# fancybox 2: call to all iframes with JS?

Tags: jquery, class, iframe, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox 2 with iframes and I'm not experienced in JQuery.
I have different classes for styling iframes and I want to do some general settings with JS.

I can call one specific iframe-class with:

```
$(".my_iframe").fancybox({
```

So I need something like:

```
$(".fancybox.iframe").fancybox({
```

In the official demo of fancybox 2 it's described, that the class "fancybox.iframe" will set the type to iframe. This works with the following html:

```
<a class="fancybox.iframe my_iframe" href="iframe.html" title="test">My Iframe</a>
```

what I want is to set default settings for every iframe and some specific settings for only some iframes, so I don't have to set new settings for every classname that changes...

thx for your help!

EDIT:

Here's an example what I want:

I've two links:

```
<li><a class="fancyframe" href="iframe.html" title="Dies ist ein iframe... sehr schön!">Iframe</a></li>
<li><a class="fancyframe my_iframe" href="iframe.html" title="Dies ist ein iframe... sehr schön!">My Iframe</a></li>
```

And two JS:

```
$(".fancyframe").fancybox({
    type : 'iframe',
});

$(".my_iframe").fancybox({
    width       : '75%',
    height      : '75%',
    autoScale   : false,
    // etc...
});
```

The second one (.my_iframe) should get the settings of .fancyframe (in this case the type).
.fancyframe would than be the reference for my default iframe settings.

Is this possible?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `class` for your style and one for fancybox. You may skip the class `fancybox.iframe` and set the `type` within you custom fancybox script so

```
<a class="fancybox my_iframe" ...
```

where `fancybox` class is used to fire fancybox and the (changing) `my_iframe` class for styling

then this script will open the iframe

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 width: 640, // or whatever
 height: 320,
 type: "iframe"
});
```

Comment: I edited the quesetion... but if there is no easy solution I'll rewrite the default settings in every specific JS... it's not that much :)